# Importing bookmarks to PDF with Latex

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, pdf, bookmarks

I have bookmark text that contains titles and their page locations on a specific PDF:

```
chapter 1: xyz  page 200
chapter 2: xau  page 234
chapter 3: dae  page 344
chapter 4: dar  page 452
...
```

what package is best to import these bookmarks into the PDF?

Comment: Reworded: You have an existing PDF and you wish to add PDF bookmarks to specific pages?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: See package `bookmark`.

Comment: How was the original PDF created? Or are you creating it using (La)TeX?

Comment: The PDF is a 5000+ pages scan of an old book, then processed for OCR.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can add a bunch of fixed bookmarks to specific pages in an existing PDF:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages,bookmark}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{big5000pagebook}

\bookmark[dest={page.200}]{Chapter 1: xyz}
\bookmark[dest={page.234}]{Chapter 2: xau}
\bookmark[dest={page.344}]{Chapter 3: dae}
\bookmark[dest={page.452}]{Chapter 4: dar}
...

\end{document}
```